# .NET Core 7 authorized controller always returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, .net-7.0

I created a new .NET Core 7 project with the classic `WeatherForecastController`.

Then I follow this post to add authentication via JWT: https://wildermuth.com/2022/12/07/changes-in-jwt-bearer-tokens-in-dotnet-7

I modified the code as mentioned in the post but all my calls from Postman always return 401 even if I set the bearer token in authorization.

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`WeatherForecastController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", 
            "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I created a new project.
I pasted the same lines of code of Program.cs and WeatherForecastController.cs from the first project which didn't work.
Result: The new project works as I expect.
I can not explain the reason for the two different behaviors, since the code is identical!

Comment: WHat's your appsettings.json look? How you get the token ?

Comment: You are missing `AddAuthentication` .

Comment: As you can read in the linked post, in Net 7 it is no longer necessary to add AddAuthentication.
To generate the token I used the "dotnet user-jwts create" command as mentioned in the post.
At the moment no check is made on the validity of the token, but only its presence is checked.
I've edited the original question to describe the weird behavior I have now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

When I use the "dotnet user-jwts create" command to create a token this section is added to the project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>c03578d3-5c38-40e3-b353-b19701736efb</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

which is probably used to validate the token

In my first project this section was not present